# How to get pdf file from associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, pdf

I have an associative array named $pdfc[]. I have to convert this associative array to pdf file on server using codeigniter and php.I am using cezpdf library to convert into pdf file on server.Below code works for less number of columns(3-4). For more number of columns(>8), what should I change in my code?

```
//below is associative array
$pdfc[] = array('1000','2000','30000','10','15','16','17','20','111');
$pdfc[] = array('3000','4000','5000','10','12',14','16','20','111');
$pdfc[] = array('2000','4000','5000','20','12','10','11','12','111');
//code to convert 
$h = array('1st distance','2nd distance','3rd distance','4th distance','5th distance','6th distance','7th distance','8th distance','9th distance');
$this->load->library('cezpdf');
$this->cezpdf->ezTable($pdfc, $h, 'code', array('width'=>550));
$this->cezpdf->ezStream(array('download' => 1));
```

Comment: What error are you getting, if any? Does it work? Does it download as expected but with a wrong format?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Why not just use DOMPDF? The docs for cezpdf are terrible. It's no wonder you can't figure it out.

Comment: I am not getting any error but I am not getting any output

Comment: I used your unaltered code and it works for me. Your problem is not in this code.

Comment: Actually I have 9 columns....so I am not getting any output....what should I use for more rows?

Comment: Although I am chnaging width, I am not getting correct output